# Apex donut chart - cant get labels to update

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I am trying to get Apex charts (in Vue.js) to also update their labels.
I am using the following example as a basis:

https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/pie-charts/update-donut/

I did a very basic chart to demonstrate the issue. It has data items and 3 labels in the begining.
The update button is wired to the update event.
When you click it the data changes but the labels doesn't.
Tried both - directly setting:

```
this.chartOptions.labels = [] ...
```

And using vue mechanism as well:

```
this.$set(this.chartOptions, "labels", ["d", "e", "f"]);
```

None of them seem to be changing the labels though.

Here's the code pen for it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-basic-example-z72rk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
<template>
  <div class="example">
    <label>{{updated}}</label>
    <apexcharts width="300" height="300" type="donut" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexcharts>
    <button v-on:click="changeChart">Update</button>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
    import VueApexCharts from "vue-apexcharts";

    export default {
      name: "Chart",
      components: {
        apexcharts: VueApexCharts
      },
      data: function() {
        return {
          updated: "Not updated",
          chartOptions: {
            chart: {
              id: "basic-donut"
            },
            labels: ["a", "b", "c"]
          },
          series: [30, 40, 45]
        };
      },
      methods: {
        changeChart() {
          this.series = [1, 2, 3];
          this.chartOptions.labels = ["d", "e", "f"];
          this.$set(this.chartOptions, "labels", ["d", "e", "f"]);
          this.$set(this, "updated", "Updated");
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

I think I am missing some understanding on how Apex pie / donut chart work, but I can't seem to find this in the documentation either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating `chartOptions` should cause an update.

Here is the full working code which I just tested and it worked fine

```js
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <button @click="updateLabels()">Update Labels</button>

    <apexcharts type="donut" width="280" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from "vue-apexcharts";

export default {
  name: "Chart",
  components: {
    apexcharts: VueApexCharts
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      series: [44, 55, 41, 17, 15],
      chartOptions: {
        labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateLabels: function() {
      this.series= [Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10]
      this.chartOptions = {
        labels: [Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10],
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-update-labels-in-donut-chart-qhiht)

Comment: I updated the sandbox to demonstrate this + updating series as this is what I needed. Looks like your approach is better. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-update-labels-in-donut-chart-12lu9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: If you are updating both series and labels, I have updated the answer to illustrate a more performant way. Otherwise, updating series in chartOptions will cause 2 renders.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation over how to update your chart is overhere: https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts

For updating the labels you have to add this to your method:

```
  this.chartOptions = {
     labels: ["d", "e", "f"]
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately this (and any "reactive" variations I could think of) did not seem to work. See my answer on how I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error (as I couldn't find the right way to properly do it in Vue style), here is how I was able to update the labels:

**Updating labels, call:**

```
  ApexCharts.exec('chartId', "updateOptions", {
    labels: labels,
    series: series
  });
```

It seems that in Vue, you still need to "fallback" to the vanilla JS methods of ApexCharts, instead of relaying on the reactive way.

I will wait to see if there are comments that support my way of doing it and mark this as answer if so.

The interesting thing is that the series seem to update by directly updating the array, but labels does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in React apex chart where redial bar updates but the value in center does not (because I wanted to use different value for both).

You can add id with Math.random() function in chart Options and it'll solve the issue

```
  options: {
      chart: {
       id: `chard_id_${Math.random()}`, <<< here
       width: 380,
       type: 'pie',
     }
  }
```